# php affected_rows seems not to work

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone,please, explain what's the problem with the following code?

```
<?php  
  $db=new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','apeirosto');          
  $query="UPDATE  INBOX SET autodelete=1 WHERE messageid=129";
  $result=$db->query($query);
  echo $result->affected_rows; 
?>
```

Table `INBOX` has `messageid` as its primary key and `autodelete`is one of its fields. Whereas everything is ok with UPDATE echo does not return anything. The same problem happens with :

```
if ($result->affected_rows==0)
```

Which always returns true!
I cannot understand...

Comment: what is this echoing `echo $result->affected_rows`

Comment: Change `if ($result->affected_rows==0)` to `if ($result->affected_rows = 0)` Becasue what you are doing is saying that `$result->affected_rows` has a value of `0`

Comment: try a var_dump($db->error);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how `affected_rows()` work.

You need to pass the DB connection variable to it

```
$db->affected_rows;
```

Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

**Object oriented style**

> int $mysqli->affected_rows;

Example pulled from the manual

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
...
$mysqli->query("UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
```